# wget ssl alert handshake failure - Closed fd 396

Tags: ssl, https, wget, handshake

I am trying to download files from an https site and keep getting the following error (could not find anything on "closed fd 396):

```
Caching www.lorealparisusa.com => 52.201.177.165 23.23.70.25
Connecting to www.lorealparisusa.com|52.201.177.165|:443... seconds 0,00,    
conectado.
Created socket 396.
Releasing 0x01ebbcd0 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake failed.
Closed fd 396
No se pudo establecer la conexión SSL.
```

(could not establish SSL connection)
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.11.4 on Windows-MinGW.
No authentication is required to access the website.